# How to compile code using `__declspec(dllexport)` for Linux

Tags: c++, gcc

There are a few questions out there about `__declspec(dllexport)`, but none seem to fit my use case:

1. Source code was originally written for Windows and uses `__declspec(dllexport)`.
2. Would like to recompile for a Linux target *without modifying the source*.

I am trying to use [GCC 11.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.4.0/gcc/Microsoft-Windows-Function-Attributes.html), which mentions:

> You can use `__declspec(dllexport)` as a synonym for `__attribute__ ((dllexport))` for compatibility with other compilers.

I can't seem to get this to work, however.

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token
    8 | #define dll_export __declspec(dllexport)

error: ‘dllexport’ was not declared in this scope
   23 | void __declspec(dllexport) _Err_msg(int err, char*& msg);
```

Hoping that there are some magic GCC flags that I am missing, or another kind of non-invasive shim I could use to get this to compile for Linux. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Since that is an MSVC extension you probably will need some form of conditional compilation anyway

Comment: As I mentioned, hoping to do this without changing the source code (since this would be an extensive project)! If the answer is "that's not possible," this is still a different question than the above.

Comment: What would the problem be with changing the source code? Conditional compilation when supporting multiple OS's is in my experience sometimes unaviodable and easy to test.

Comment: Difference in changing hundreds of files that are known to be stable for Windows builds versus simply changing an ops pipeline. In this case there are also licensing ramifications to changing the source.

Comment: Fair enough, I can't think of any (quick) solution.  The code change to add conditional compilation is automatable (a somewhat smart find replace/codgen thing). But that would still leave the licensing option. (Voted to reopen, since dupe doesn't seem to apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about -D option?

-D name=definition

The contents of definition are tokenized and processed as if they appeared during translation phase three in a ‘#define’ directive. In particular, the definition is truncated by embedded newline characters.

```
gcc -D__declspec(dllexport)=__attribute__((dllexport)) ...
```

Similar for other Windows specific stuff

Comment: I've got this working using `-D'__declspec(dllexport)=__attribute((visibility("default")))'`! Note that you need to wrap the option in single quotes if it contains special characters. I'm also using `visibility("default")` instead of `dllexport` (which I think is meant for GCC builds targeting Windows).